# arcpy - using an external table to iteratively change parameters into my code

Tags: python, jupyter, arcpy

I am working with python 2.7 and arcpy under Jupyter notebook environment.
I would like to adapt iteratively my code to a reference table.

This is my reference table which contains the 3 variables that I use for the tool I am running in arpcy:

```
  RegY          HunCal    CRY
    1            1718     BL1
    1            1112     JU1
    1            1112     JU1
    1            1213     JU1
```

This is a simple xls table which I imported to my jupyter notebook. I have it as a visual reference for when I have to change these variables in my code.

In the beginning, I was doing it by hand because they were a few changes to make. But now there are more than 150 changes to adapt, and, this amount increases with time. Therefore, I would like to modify the code in such a way that it uses the reference table to iterate through every feature each time the reference table changes.

This is the code I am using:

```
# 2011
# Set geoprocessor object property to overwrite existing output
arcpy.gp.overwriteOutput = True


arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\GeoData\simSear\SBA_D.gdb'
    
# Process: Group Similar Features  
SS.SimilaritySearch("redD_RegY_1_1112","blackD_CRY_JU1_1112","SS_JU1_1112","NO_COLLAPSE",
                        "MOST_SIMILAR","ATTRIBUTE_PROFILES",0,
                        "Temperatur;Precipitat", 'DateFin')
```

How can I adapt the code in such a way that the variables from the reference table are inserted into my code in the following way:

- From the reference table, the values from `RegY` would be replaced in `redD_RegY_**1**_1112`.
- The values from `CRY` would be replaced in `blackD_CRY_**JU1**_1112` and `SS_**JU1**_1112`
- The values from `HunCal` would be replaced in `redD_RegY_1_**1112**`, `blackD_CRY_JU1_**1112**`, `SS_JU1_**1112**`

Any hint or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate through each row of the table to get your reference table values, then use them to build the unique strings for your input, candidate, and output features.

```py
for row in table:
    regY = row[0]
    hunCal = row[1]
    cry = row[2]

    input_features_to_match = 'redD_RegY_{}_{}'.format(regY, hunCal)
    candidate_features = 'blackD_CRY_{}_{}'.format(cry, hunCal)
    output_features = 'SS_{}_{}'.format(cry, hunCal)

    SS.SimilaritySearch(
        input_features_to_match,
        candidate_features,
        output_features,
        'NO_COLLAPSE',
        'MOST_SIMILAR',
        'ATTRIBUTE_PROFILES',
        0,
        'Temperatur;Precipitat',
        'DateFin')
```

Or much more compactly:

```py
for row in table:
    SS.SimilaritySearch(
        'redD_RegY_{}_{}'.format(row[0], row[1]),
        'blackD_CRY_{}_{}'.format(row[2], row[1]),
        'SS_{}_{}'.format(row[2], row[1]),
        'NO_COLLAPSE',
        'MOST_SIMILAR',
        'ATTRIBUTE_PROFILES',
        0,
        'Temperatur;Precipitat',
        'DateFin')
```